# In the process of categorising my blogs but keep hitting the wall "Page not found 404"

Tags: django

I am a complete beginner so I apologies for my noobiness explanation. I am in the process of categorising my blogs.

I created a model -> migrated it -> imported in view.py -> Imported the view that I created into urls.py -> and created URL for my new page but when I add the href to other pages (home) it takes me to the error.

My codes:
models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content=models.TextField()
date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
category = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Engineering')


def __str__(self):
    return self.title



def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Views.py:

```
from .models import Post, Category

class CategoryListView(ListView):
model = Post
template_name= 'blog/category_posts.html'
context_object_name = 'posts'
ordering = ['-date_posted']
paginate_by = 3
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
PostListView, 
PostDetailView, 
PostCreateView, 
PostUpdateView, 
PostDeleteView,
UserPostListView,
CategoryListView)

path('category/<str:category>/', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category-posts'),
```

home.html

```
 <a href="{% url 'category-posts' %}">{{ post.category }}</a>
```

Comment: I don't see `urlpatterns ` in your urls.py.

Comment: I have put in Url patterns, just hadn't shown it. it is within urlpatterns = [].

Answer (score 0):

You should also pass the category in your url, like this

```
 <a href="{% url 'category-posts' post.category %}">{{ post.category }}</a>
```

Because your url needs a str parameter category.

Comment: Thanks, Arun I tried that. I get a new error. "NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'category-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<category>[^/]+)/$']"

Comment: Sorry, it should be  `<a href="{% url 'category-posts' post.category %}">{{ post.category }}</a>`. I have updated my answer also

Comment: I just added "post.category" instead of just category. it seems to have gotten rid of the error but just does not list it into categories

Comment: @SM can you explain what is the issue now? Didnt understand...

Comment: at the moment when I click on the category link next to my post. it takes me to a category page that lists all of my posts.

Comment: similar thing happened when clicking on user. but we used the get-queryset function to sort it out. 
  def get_queryset(self):
  user=get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
  return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')

Comment: Basically when you click on the category link, you want to show a page where you show all the posts of that category which you clicked. So you have to write a filter query with your posts model for that category in this view class. Just like how you did for the user usecase in the above comment. But that is a different issue and the answer for this question is as per the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Arun said.

I think you need to set `url_patters` in your urls.py.  Something like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
PostListView, 
PostDetailView, 
PostCreateView, 
PostUpdateView, 
PostDeleteView,
UserPostListView,
CategoryListView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('category/<str:category>/', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category-posts'),
]
```

Comment: thanks for the comments. But I have checked and made changes. I get a new error now NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'category-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<category>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: I just added "post.category" instead of just category. it seems to have gotten rid of the error but just does not list it into categories